# Verify if an iam username already exist

Tags: python, boto

Do you know how can I verify if an iam username already exist?

Im trying with code below, using get_user, but when user dont exist I got an error: `The user with name teste cannot be found`.

Do you know the way to do this?

```
c = boto.iam.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
while True:
    username = raw_input("Username:")
    password = raw_input("Password:")
    if not username or not password:
        print "Please enter a valid username and password"
    if c.get_user(username):
        print "Username already exist, please enter a different username..."
```

New try:

```
while True:
    username = raw_input("Username:")
    password = raw_input("Password:")
    if not username or not password:
        print "Please enter a valid username and password"
    try:
        if not c.get_user(username):
            print "Username valid"
    except BotoServerError, e:
        print "Username already exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a try/except around the call and handle the exception.

```
from boto.exception import BotoServerError
c = boto.iam.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
while True:
    username = raw_input("Username:")
    password = raw_input("Password:")
    if not username or not password:
        print "Please enter a valid username and password"
    try:
        c.get_user(username)
    except BotoServerError, e:
        print(e.message)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im having an error: "No module named exceptions".

Comment: Sorry, it's ``boto.exception`` not ``boto.exceptions``.  I fixed the example.

Comment: I update my question with a new try. Because I just want to enter in except if username already exist, if get_user(username) returns something. But Im always entering in except even when the user dont exist. Do you see where is the issue?